# Can't float the nav bar

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I want to float my `nav-bar` to the right of my screen, but I can't figure out how to make it. I tried to play with the `margin` property, but that just breaks. I know it's a mess, but I haven't removed any unnecessary code trying to resolve my problem.

Below the code.

```css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap");
    /* font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; */
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    }
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1.15rem;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0.5em 1.3em;
      border-width: 2px;
      border-style: solid;
    }
    .container {
      width: 95%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /*Home Section*/
    header {
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 1em;
    }
    .logo {
      max-width: 180px;
      max-height: 180px;
    }
    #nav-ul {
      margin: 2em;
      padding-top: 0.7em;
      padding-bottom: 0.7em;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .nav-item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0em;
    }
    .nav-links {
      font-weight: 900;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1rem;
      padding: 0.3em;
      color: white;
    }
    .nav-links:hover,
    .nav-links:focus {
      color: lightgray;
    }
    #home-section {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100vw;
      background-image: url(imgs/home-section-background.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      padding: 10em 0;
    }
    .title {
      color: white;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
    .button-green {
      margin-top: 1.8em;
      color: rgb(3, 204, 30);
      border-color: rgb(12, 255, 45);
    }
    .button-green:hover,
    .button-green:focus {
      background-color: rgb(8, 163, 26);
    }
    /* About section */
    #about-examples {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .description-text {
      background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
      color: white;
      padding: 3em;
      width: 100vw;
      margin-left: -2.5%;
      outline: 2px solid rgb(12, 255, 45);
      outline-offset: -2.1em;
      position: relative;
    }
    .description-text p {
      text-align: justify;
    }
    .description-text h1 {
      font-size: 1.3em;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0.8em;
      background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
      color: rgb(12, 255, 45);
      padding: 0 0.5em;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    
    /*Media quiries*/
    @media (min-width: 60rem) {
      .title {
        font-size: 4rem;
      }
      .nav-links {
        font-size: 2rem;
        float: right;
      }
      .nav-item {
      }
      .button {
        font-size: 2rem;
      }
      .logo {
        float: left;
        margin: 1em;
      }
      #nav-ul {
        float: right;
      }
      .description-text {
        font-size: 3em;
      }
      .description-text p {
        font-size: 0.5em;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>About Me</title>
        <link href="ResponsiveWeb.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <img src="imgs/logo.jpg" alt="company logo" class="logo" />
          <ul id="nav-ul">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#home-section" class="nav-links">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#about-examples" class="nav-links">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#contacts" class="nav-links">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </header>
        <!--Company name goes here-->
        <section class="home" id="home-section">
          <div class="containter">
            <h1 class="title">Making proffesional design and development</h1>
            <a href="#" class="button button-green">See our work</a>
          </div>
        </section>
        <!--Company description goes here-->
        <div class="container">
          <section class="about-company" id="about-examples">
            <div class="description-text">
              <h1>What we do</h1>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh sit
                amet commodo nulla facilisi.
              </p>
              <p>
                Nam eget sem sed sem rutrum efficitur. Nullam lorem nunc, porta et
                faucibus semper, suscipit id mauris. Sed nisi eros, mollis at mollis
                a, porta et sapien. Fusce blandit tempus justo. Aenean erat magna,
                semper nec commodo quis, feugiat sit amet lacus. Vestibulum tempor
                ornare fermentum. Vestibulum egestas imperdiet libero, sed egestas
                purus varius a. Mauris consequat ligula ipsum, at faucibus lectus
                blandit quis. Donec congue eros sed est sollicitudin, in ultricies
                lorem consectetur. Maecenas suscipit tortor orci, id pellentesque
                nisi maximus at. In laoreet turpis id tempor dapibus. Nunc facilisis
                egestas ex et ullamcorper. Mauris nunc felis, porttitor nec porta
                cursus, egestas vitae tellus. Ut commodo in metus eget blandit.
                Maecenas vestibulum dictum neque, at dictum arcu lobortis nec. Donec
                quis augue arcu.
              </p>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <!--Work Example-->
        <section class="work-example">
          <h1>Example of our work</h1>
          <figure class="port-example">
            <img
              src="imgs/Portfolio-pic-01 Jeremy Bishop.jpg"
              alt="Beautiful tree"
            />
            <figcaption class="port-description">
              <p>Photo by Jeremy Bishop</p>
              <a href="#" class="button button-green button-small"
                >See project details</a
              >
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
    
          <figure class="port-example">
            <img src="imgs/Portfolio-pic-02 Jay Mantri.jpg" alt="Fog over forest" />
            <figcaption class="port-description">
              <p>Photo by Jay Mantri</p>
              <a href="#" class="button button-green button-small"
                >See project details</a
              >
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
    
          <figure class="port-example">
            <img
              src="imgs/Portfolio-pic-03 Riccardo Chiarini.jpg"
              alt="Beautiful lake"
            />
            <figcaption class="port-description">
              <p>Photo by Riccardo Chiarini</p>
              <a href="#" class="button button-green button-small"
                >See project details</a
              >
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
    
          <figure class="port-example">
            <img
              src="imgs/Portfolio-pic-04 redcharlie.jpg"
              alt="Beautiful tree in forest"
            />
            <figcaption class="port-description">
              <p>Photo by redcharlie</p>
              <a href="#" class="button button-green button-small"
                >See project details</a
              >
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
    
          <figure class="port-example">
            <img
              src="imgs/Portfolio-pic-05 Vincent van Zalinge.jpg"
              alt="Bird on brnanch"
            />
            <figcaption class="port-description">
              <p>Photo by Vincent van Zalinge</p>
              <a href="#" class="button button-green button-small"
                >See project details</a
              >
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
    
          <figure class="port-example">
            <img
              src="imgs/Portfolio-pic-06 eberhard grossgasteiger.jpg"
              alt="Fog over mountains"
            />
            <figcaption class="port-description">
              <p>Photo by eberhard grossgasteiger</p>
              <a href="#" class="button button-green button-small"
                >See project details</a
              >
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </section>
    
        <footer id="contacts">
          <p>Work hours: Mon-Fri 8:00 AM - 16:00 PM</p>
          <br />
          <p>You can contact us here:</p>
          <br />
          <ul class="contact-links">
            <li class="contact-link"><a class="contact" href="#">A</a></li>
            <li class="contact-link"><a class="contact" href="#">B</a></li>
            <li class="contact-link"><a class="contact" href="#">C</a></li>
          </ul>
        </footer>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/tkhosla/h7neu8t0/3/

Remove position absolute from your header and apply float left to logo and float right to your nav.

I also changed the color of your links to black so they are visible. I removed the margin and padding around them as well to make them aligned to the logo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the header is not wide enough. In your CSS you can set the width of the header to 100%.

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after removing `position: absolute` from the header in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is your header isn't big enough.
So add to the header "**width: 100%;**"

```
header {
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 1em;
   width: 100%
}
```

Then add "**float: right;**" to your #nav-ul:

```
#nav-ul {
  margin: 2em;
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  padding-bottom: 0.7em;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
}
```